# Triple turnstile symbol

Tags: symbols

I want a triple-bar turnstile symbol to go alongside the single-bar `\vdash` and the double-bar `\vDash`  – a symbol the same size and weight as the Computer Modern turnstiles:

[image]

(The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List tells me there is is a stix version, but it doesn't really match the CM symbols.)

I can cook up something that almost works with `|` and `\equiv` and `\raisebox` and `\tiny` etc.

But I'm just wondering if someone has a nicer solution out there!

Comment: With "the other Computer Modern symbols" you mean the `amssymb` symbols? Could you include an image that illustrates what you are looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just superimpose the two present symbols (`\vDdashA`). If you want more control over the spacing, `\vDdashB` is another possibility (I don't know if there are better possibilities to get the dash than using a `\clipbox`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{trimclip} % for \vDdashB

\newcommand*\vDdashA{%
  \mathrel{%
    \ooalign{$\vdash$\cr$\vDash$}%
  }%
}
\def\@clipped@vdash{%
  \raise .6ex\hbox{\clipbox{0pt .6ex 0pt .6ex}{$\vdash$}}%
}
\newcommand*\vDdashB{%
  \mathrel{%
    \ooalign{%
      $\vdash$\cr
      \raise  .3ex\hbox{\@clipped@vdash}\cr
      \raise -.3ex\hbox{\@clipped@vdash}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\(a \vdash b\)

\(a \vDdashA b\)

\(a \vDdashB b\)

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: The second version is typographically very neat indeed!